# Permission denied on trying to write file

Tags: python, django, windows, python-2.7, django-models

I am a python/Django newbie. I am creating folders in my view using:

```
os.makedirs(path)
```

The path is different for each file and depends on username and filename combination. On trying to write a file in this folder, I get this error:

```
IOError at /view_name/
[Errno 13] Permission denied: u'<filepath>'
```

This is on my windows system. Even on trying to change permission to write from read only, doesn't changes it(its default and only attribute for folders in windows). What should I do?

Comment: @eryksun No, I just replaced filepath with /filepath/. Changed it to placeholder. The path was correct.

Comment: As far as file security is concerned, log the output of `subprocess.check_output('whoami /user /groups /fo list', universal_newlines=True)` and `subprocess.check_output('icacls "%s"' % filepath, universal_newlines=True)`.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that the directory already exists, which, according to [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.makedirs) should raise an error.

It is also possible that the directory is used in some other program, like explorer, and that needs to be closed first.

A third option I can think of is that the default permissions for a directory on your system don't allow reading by a user, in which case your program would need to be run as an administrator or use the `win32security` module from [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) to manually set permissions for the directory(although that may also not work if you don't have permission to change permissions).